# Adding smAction on shiny datatables

Tags: menu, datatables, shiny, action, dt

Here's an example of smAction on plot,.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyMenus)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = 
    fluidPage(
      smNavBar("testMenu", "shinyMB", full.width = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, 

               textInput("n", "Sample Size", value = 1000)
      ),

      plotOutput("testPlot"),

      smContextMenu("context1","testPlot",

                    smAction("action1", "Normal"),
                    smAction("action2", "Lognormal"),
                    smAction("action3", "Uniform")

      )

    ),
  server = 
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$testPlot <- renderPlot({
        plot(rnorm(input$n))
      })


    })

runApp(app)
```

I am trying to do the same thing , user right clicks and the menu shows three actions on a datatable instead of plot , this is what I have so far

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyMenus)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    h2('The mtcars data'),

    dataTableOutput('mytable'),

      smContextMenu("context1","mytable",

                    smAction("action1", "Action1"),
                    smAction("action2", "Action2"),
                    smAction("action3", "Action3")

      )

    ),
  server = 
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
        mtcars
      })


    })

runApp(app)
```

This is not working. I am not sure what I am missing, any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.